# Gitsigns color customization

Tags: neovim, colorscheme

I am customizing the color scheme of the gitsigns column on the left.

I managed to change all different symbols using the following:

```
hi DiffAdd
hi DiffChange
hi DiffDelete
hi DiffText
```

I cannot figure out how to change the remaining gray background corresponding to lines with no changes.

[image: Background color wrong]

Comment: Can you tell us which plugin do you use to display the Git marks?

Comment: I use https://github.com/lewis6991/gitsigns.nvim

Comment: Then you have to use SignColumn

Answer (score 2):

For `lewis6991/gitsigns.nvim` you have to use: `hi SignColumn`

For `mhinz/vim-signify` you have to use: `hi LineNr`

Comment: I already set this one to a black background as well. It controls the line numbers. But it does not change the signs column is on it's left.